# PUT and DELETE requests not allowed in apache 2.4

Tags: apache

I'm trying to create RESTFul API on my server using PHP. No problems with GET or POST requests, but I can't get PUT or DELETE requests working.

At first, I tried without configuring Apache: all I get is a 403 Unauthorized error. Then I use Limit:

```apache
<Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
  Require all granted
</Limit>
```

I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

From here, I've tried multiple configurations (AllowMethods, ...) but still get the 405 error.
When I activate upper level of Apache's logs, It indicate all is fine, but still return 405 code:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 43259] mod_authz_core.c(817): AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 43259] mod_authz_core.c(817): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[http:trace3] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(1125): Response sent with status 405, headers:
[http:trace5] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(1134):   Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 06:55:24 GMT
[http:trace5] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(1137):   Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
[http:trace4] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(955):   Allow: GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD
[http:trace4] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(955):   Content-Length: 306
[http:trace4] [pid 43259] http_filters.c(955):   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I read sometimes server web applications like Jira can cause this, but I only install PhpMyAdmin.

How can I use PUT or DELETE requests ?

*NOTE: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

A global Apache2 configuration /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf define the following rules:

```apache
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
  Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
  Require all denied
</LimitExcept >
```

I'm not sure why the `<Limit>` was partially ignore in .htaccess (error 405 instead 403 when active) but work if granted all with no `<Limit>`.